# Access elements of a child class object stored in a vector of type parent's class in c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
class Parent{
 private:
    int a;
};
class Child:public parent{
private:
    int b;
};
class outsideWorld{
 private:
   vector<Parent> myvec; //note vector of type parent class.
 public:
   void myfunc(){
      Child obj;
      obj.b = 30;
      myvec.push_back(obj);
    }
   void display(){
        //help needed here
        //trying to display elements of child class from myvec but not happening.
        //looking to display 30 - value of b.
   }
}
```

I want to display the value of b using the vector but unable to. friend function for parent class is also not working for me. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are no `Child`s in your vector. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Comment: I'm talking about accessing an element, how is it related to this Store derived class objects in base class variables (5 answers)? I don't understand. someone else pointed out it is object slicing. I was able to understand that much before posting here. but don't know how to proceed. Can anybody please show me how to access the element?